# Как сделать красивую анимацию на фоне?

Tags: css, анимация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую же анимацию на фоне, как на этом [сайте](http://discordapp.com/login).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышеперечисленное, плюс

1. Установить у фона параметр `z-index` меньше (желательно намного), чем у контента, который будет поверх него
2. Для анимации через css можно использовать `@keyframes` [читать подробнее тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy)